# create insertion rule on view returning id

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, rule, sql-returning

I have a table private.products and a view public.products representing that table. And I want to create entries in private.products while inserting into view, it all works right, except that I also what to return the inserted id:

```
CREATE RULE insert_product 
AS ON INSERT TO public.products DO INSTEAD 
INSERT INTO private.products (name) VALUES (new.name) RETURNING products.id;
ERROR:  RETURNING list has too few entries
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of [the relevant documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createrule.html) suggests that you must return the same number of columns as the `products` view actually has.  This is because the rule is not a query itself; it is a rule for rewriting queries.  The queries may have their own `RETURNING` clauses, which could refer to any of the view's columns.  Your rule can rewrite those clauses, but only if you specify what to rewrite each returned column into.